# Nodejs- Recursive function not being called from inside a successful request call

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, request

I have an array of objects. For each element of the array, I need to make a POST request. Once the POST request is successful, I need to get the child objects of the element and repeat the procedure. I implemented this using recursive function calls

- roottypeid

  - type1

    - type11

      - type111
    - type12
  - type2

    - type21
    - type22

This is the hierarchy that needs to be followed. Only the first level, i.e, type1 and type2 are getting created. Why is the recursive function not being called for the child objects?

```
function func1(typeid) {
  getTypes(typeid).then(function(responseData) { //getTypes returns all the child types of a given parent typeid
    var types = JSON.parse(responseData);

    AuthClient.credentials.getToken()
      .then(function(token) {
        types.forEach(function(element) {

          var options = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: url,
            qs: {
              access_token: token.accessToken
            },
            headers: {
              'content-type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: element,
            json: true
          }
          request(options, function(error, response, body) {
            if (error) throw new Error(error)
            if (response.statuscode === 200) {
              func1(element.id);
              console.log(body);
            }
          });
        });
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
      });
  });
}

func1(roottypeid);
```

Comment: If I were you, I would restructure the code with async/await

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the error is not in the code you supplied; it's definitely not a recursion error.  I can get it to work with your exact code by faking out the services you're calling.

Double-check for silly errors like typos.  (Does your service return `statuscode` or `statusCode`? Etc.)

```js
const AuthClient = {credentials: {getToken: () =>
  Promise.resolve({accessToken: 'foobar'})
}}

const getTypes = (typeid) => 
  new Promise((resolve, _) => resolve(({
      roottypeid: `[{"id": "type1"}, {"id": "type2"}]`,
      type1: `[{"id": "type11"}, {"id": "type12"}]`,
      type11: `[{"id": "type111"}]`,
      type2: `[{"id": "type21"}, {"id": "type22"}]`
    })[typeid] || `[]`)
  )

const request = (options, fn) => setTimeout(
  () => fn (
    null, 
    {statuscode: 200}, 
    `fake results for ${JSON.stringify(options.body)}`
  ),
  10
)

const url = 'http://example.com'

const roottypeid = 'roottypeid'

function func1(typeid) {
  getTypes(typeid).then(function(responseData) { //getTypes returns all the child types of a given parent typeid
    var types = JSON.parse(responseData);

    AuthClient.credentials.getToken()
      .then(function(token) {
        types.forEach(function(element) {

          var options = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: url,
            qs: {
              access_token: token.accessToken
            },
            headers: {
              'content-type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: element,
            json: true
          }
          request(options, function(error, response, body) {
            if (error) throw new Error(error)
            if (response.statuscode === 200) {
              func1(element.id);
              console.log(body);
            }
          });
        });
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
      });
  });
}

func1(roottypeid);
```

Comment: Thank you for this response. You were right. It was a silly typo error.